# unable to connect to mysql on aws using windows machine

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

- I have already put my mysql instance and ec2 instance in same availability region
- I have no firewall issues

[image: This is my instance configuration]

- Here, in **RDS(sg-b46d6ccf)** ,I have  already given my custom IP for inbound rule and I have even tried with `anyone` option

But somehow when I write `mysql -h myinstance.123456789012.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p` , I am not able to get it connected successfully. 
 But it says **ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myinstance.rds.amazonaws.com' (10060 "Unknown error")**.

i have even tried to connect via mysql workbench, but it is also not working. So here, What I am missing to get it connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seems to have everything inside a VPC, you need to make it public

Comment: yes, I had everything in one VPC. So what I did was , I created separate VPC and security group for that. and it started working

Comment: How did you make it working? I created a VPC and Security Groups and added inboun and outbound rules for my ip but still not working